# Android how change background options menu

Tags: java, android, android-layout

i have trouble! My options menu (popup menu) background doesn't change.

My Code Style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel
</style>
```

And i generate background image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukdTk.png

But my background still has a dark color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an easy way to change the colors in Actionbar. Use "ActionBar Generator" and copy paste all file in your res folder and change your theme in Android.manifest file.